# Problema con inputs desde el FormArray Angular 11

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, input

El problema es que estoy partiendo de este ejemplo para crear mi formulario en Angular 11,

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-example

Donde cuando le doy en un input del FormArray, solo puedo digitar una sola tecla y se sale del input, no entiendo el porque y el ejemplo tiene el mismo problema, en mi codigo lo tengo asi (a claro que tengo Typescript en modo Strict).

Les agradezco cualquier colaboración, ya que he buscado y no encuentro solución a mi problema.
**component.ts**

```
export class OcasionalgComponent implements OnInit {
 Formulario: FormGroup;
 view:boolean;
 constructor(private LoginService:LoginService,private data: CentralService,private router:Router, private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.view=false;
  this.Formulario = new FormGroup({
    perten:this.fb.array([]),
  })
 }

 onagregarpertenencias() {
    var letterPattern = '^[a-zA-Z ]*$';
    var numberpattern="[0-9]+"
    const control = new FormGroup({
      'costo': new FormControl('',[Validators.required]),
      'nombre': new FormControl('',[Validators.required]),
    });
    (<FormArray>this.Formulario.get('perten')).push(control);
  }

  removerpertenencias(i:number) {
    (<FormArray>this.Formulario.get('perten')).removeAt(i);
  }

  getValiditypertenenciascost(i:number) {
    return (!((<any>this.Formulario.get('perten')).controls[i].controls.costo.valid) && ((<any>this.Formulario.get('perten')).controls[i].controls.costo.touched || (<any>this.Formulario.get('perten')).controls[i].controls.costo.dirty));
  }
 
{
```

**component.html**

```
    <form [formGroup]="Formulario">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" [hidden]="view" (click)="onagregarpertenencias()">Agregar Pertenencia</button>
                    
                    <ng-container class="form-row" formArrayName="perten">
                            <div  *ngFor="let ctrl of Formulario.get('perten')!.value; let i = index"
                            [formGroupName]="i" >
                                <div class="col-md-6 mb-3" >
                                    <label >Costo</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="cost" formControlName="costo" placeholder="Costo"  autocomplete="off" [ngClass]="{'form-control':true, 'is-invalid': getValiditypertenenciascost(i)}">
                                    
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 mb-3" >
                                    <label >Nombre</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="nom" formControlName="nombre" placeholder="Nombre"  autocomplete="off" [ngClass]="{'form-control':true, 'is-invalid': getValiditypertenenciasnom(i)}">
                                    
                                </div>
                                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" [hidden]="view" (click)="removerpertenencias(i)">Eliminar</button>
                            </div>
                        
                    </ng-container>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

el error está en el html en el *ngFor, cuando manejas formularios reactivos tienes que iterar los controls y no los values, por lo tanto debes colocar "***Formulario.controls.perten.controls***" en la sección del *ngFor y quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
<div *ngFor="let ctrl of Formulario.controls.perten.controls; let i = index"
[formGroupName]="i" >
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3" >
        <label >Costo</label>
        <input type="text" id="cost" formControlName="costo" placeholder="Costo"  autocomplete="off" [ngClass]="{'form-control':true, 'is-invalid': getValiditypertenenciascost(i)}">
        
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3" >
        <label >Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" id="nom" formControlName="nombre" placeholder="Nombre"  autocomplete="off" [ngClass]="{'form-control':true, 'is-invalid': getValiditypertenenciasnom(i)}">
        
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" [hidden]="view" (click)="removerpertenencias(i)">Eliminar</button>
</div>
```

Espero que no te haya dado la respuesta demasiado tarde y te funcione, éxitos...